# Bought new TSA suitcase, it's locked itself - how to open it?

Tags: luggage, tsa

I just bought a suitcase, so the combination is 000 (I didn't touch the numbers) and I locked it by mistake. How do I open it?

[image]

Comment: If you know the combination why not use it? Also you can open it by forcing a ballpoint pen into the zip and then pushing it along. This does not damage the zip and you can close it again afterwards.

Comment: I dont know combination, it was all time 000 when I buy it but I dont know how to open ..ps: I add image

Comment: Take it to TSA maybe?

Comment: You can buy TSA keys if you want them ...

Comment: I need pack my things, its midnighr anf I have flight in 5 hours ..I am desperate

Comment: Worst case, you can try all the combinations.

Comment: Been there, done that. Start with 001, 002, etc. It should take about 10 minutes to go through all the combinations with the three dials. Immediately write down what opens it :-)

Comment: Best answer dorothy :) I will do that

Comment: [Got a Swiss Army knife?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lXn7wrczNA) It comes with a tool to open these locks....

Comment: Even if you just go and try all numeric combinations, it's going to take you <10 minutes. There are only 999 combinations, and trying each is going to take you less than 1/2 seconds if you spin fast.

Comment: @Giorgio is right. It took me less than two minutes to find the correct code. It had locked itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

First, these numeric locks are useless, see this video on how to [Decode Luggage Locks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKdnWfWQHbw). Second, your image is blurry but if I see it correctly that's a TSA 007 isn't it? Well, here's a video on how to [pick TSA 007 locks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrYetSYCWoU).

Edit: [How to unlock a briefcase lock and figure out combo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNhiP0itSYU) another video on defeating the numlock.

Edit2: if you have a 3D printer, here are the [TSA keys](https://github.com/Xyl2k/TSA-Travel-Sentry-master-keys).

Comment: I didnt change combination, so I am looking for factory combination but obviously its not 000

Comment: I edited a little, you can easily defeat the numeric lock.

Comment: Just inserted scissors to tsa key hole and it opened ..wow such a quality lock

Comment: Also https://theintercept.com/2015/09/17/tsa-doesnt-really-care-luggage-locks-hacked/  But all these links shouldn't be any surprise.  If there is one master key in every airport in the USA, I can guarantee one is "lost" every day and crooks have been selling copies to each other since three days after they were distributed.

Comment: This TSA lock is the dumbest idea in the large confetti parade of ideas to protect the US.

Comment: Well, default locks on luggage are not really meant to be secure anyway, only to prevent the suitcase from opening accidentally. If you want security, don't use a suitcase, ship in a metal container using UPS or FedEx.

Comment: Or, if you want security, keep it on (or in ;-) your body at all times.

Answer (score 3):

The default code is 000 but you have to open it by pressing down on the small button and then pulling open the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

ALL you need to do is keep on 000 and press the tsa lock towards the lock.  It should open. I just received my replacement suitcase and had to go online to see why it also won't open.  No instructions are ever given from the company .